# TLabel Partly Font Size

Tags: delphi

I dont know but if its possible, how can I change Tlabel font size partly?

What i want :
[image]
Here is my code:

```
var
  lbl : TLabel;
  str : String;
begin
  str:= 'HELLO WORLD';
  lbl.Text:= str;
end;
```

Please don't suggest use 2 label to merge it, I have to use one label but I couldn't find how can I change size or color character by character ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard TLabel doesn't allow using different fonts. There are some such components in third-party component packs (arbitrary example -  TRTFLabel from TMS).

But you can use, for example, small `TImage`, and draw text on it's `Canvas` with different styles (losing some TLabel possibilities like autosize).

```
var
  w, h: Integer;
begin
  Image1.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
  h := Image1.Canvas.Font.Height; // in pixels
  Image1.Canvas.TextOut(0, 20 + h, 'Big');
  w := Image1.Canvas.TextWidth('Big');
  Image1.Canvas.Font.Size := 8;
  h := Image1.Canvas.Font.Height; // in pixels
  Image1.Canvas.Font.Style := Image1.Canvas.Font.Style + [fsBold];
  Image1.Canvas.TextOut(W, 20 + h, 'SmallBold');
```

Comment: can you give me an example about drawing canvas or are there any free component for this?

Comment: I'd favour a paint box over an image control

Comment: @David Heffernan It seems Timage usage for (mostly) static picture is simpler for beginner - no need to care about Paint handler and remember text and formatting.

Comment: No. This question is done. You just use a paint box and draw its canvas in its OnPaint event.